# paw custom extension to base64 decode response data

Tags: paw-app

I have a Paw request that returns some base64 data which I need to decode. I can't see how this is possible using a custom extension. Is this possible ?

Comment: It isn't possible yet, unfortunately. Extensions + Dynamic Values let you customize requests, but there is no way to perform changes on the response. That's an interesting use case, though. I'll think about it and try to make that possible in the future.

Comment: Thanks, any Idea on timescales for this one ?

Comment: Probably about two/three months...? Can't promise anything, but that's what I have in mind for now.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri is there any way to base64 decode response data in Paw now?